# PDF Type view using html and css. Page overflow problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a "document viewer" of sorts using html and css. I'm wanting the end result to look somewhat of a pdf when viewed in an iframe with no border.

I have a parent div setup with a class of paper. This has some box shadow and other styles attached to it.

```
<div class="paper">

</div>
```

Within this I have children divs setup with a class of page. This is where all the content sits for the page.

```
<div class="page">

</div>
```

My problem is when the content gets too long for a page and you scroll to the next "page" it all mixes together and looks like junk. I have attached a code pen to further assist in being able to visually see what I am struggling with.

CodePen

[CodePen Link Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vQorey?editors=1000)

Comment: You can use some display forms in your "page" class in CSS, like display: table;

Comment: @Giliapps that solved my problem except now my first page content is no longer centered?

Comment: Now you can add  text-align: center; to the page class.

Comment: @Giliapps thank you! That solved my problem! Please place in answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your page class in CSS with this:

```
.page {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### What is the problem?

If the content in your `page`s gets too long, it overflows the height end kind of "bleeds" on the next page.

### What to do?

1. You should set a fixed height of `100vh` to your `paper`
2. Then, tell it not to expand with: `overflow: scroll`
3. Use `min-height` to set the height of your `page`, instead of `height`: it will naturally expand the height of the pages instead as you content grows
4. Finally, just in case, set `overflow: hidden` to `page`

Comment: So should the container not have a fixed height?

Comment: It depends... maybe you should set a fixed height to your container. I'll update the above answer.

Comment: While that does fix the overflow issue, it causes the page to scroll prior to reaching the top of the paper. It does not really provide the desired look and feel I'm going for. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Just updated the above answer. Is it better? And, could you update the codepen, so I can see what you are talking about?

Comment: Well now by setting the overflow hidden to the container, you can not scroll to the second page.

Comment: What about using min-height instead of height?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184836/discussion-between-gaspacchio-and-mitch-evans).